# Reboot after power failure not working

Tags: reboot, ups

My bios (american megatrends) has an option to reboot after power failure which I have set only it doesn't work. I have a UPS which shuts it down correctly and then disconnects the power. When power is restored the UPS comes back up but the pc does Zip and has to be manually restarted. Whats going on and how can I sort it? I need this machine to restart while I am away for cctv monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

In the scenario you describe, the machine is in fact *not* experiencing a power failure. The UPS is signalling it to properly shut down.  So, in that sense, the BIOS is doing what it's supposed to do.

Now, if you had no UPS and you had a power failure, the BIOS would detect that and power the machine back up when power was restored.

Are there any other options in the BIOS to control booting?

Comment: It might also be wise to check if there any options on the UPS to send a wake up call to the PC after it detects restored power.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work with a real power failure either as I have discovered on a number of occasions. There are options also under acpi for wake on LAN etc but these only work if PC is sleeping rather than powered down.

Comment: Unfortunately my experiences with American Megatrends BIOSes means I'm not surprised. Have you looked for a BIOS update?

Comment: The board is discontinued now. It has a system which automatically looks for updates but it does not show any update available.